# How to insert a backslash into a PHP string to escape an exclamation mark?

Tags: php, salesforce, escaping, php-curl

I'm trying to prepare a PHP cURL request to Salesforce REST API. The PHP-cURL header requires an authorization bearer string, which uses an 'access_token' derived from a previous OAuth call.

This 'access_token' string comprises two substrings delimited by an exclamation mark, (i.e. `'substringA!substringB'`). Reusing it as-is is throwing errors as an expired or invalid token and according to the documents, the string delimiting exclamation mark needs to be escaped with a backslash (i.e. `'substringA\!substringB'`).

My attempts to insert a backslash with the PHP `str_replace()` function or build a new string from parts that include a backslash result in double backslashes and the use of single or double quotes seem to make no difference, e.g.

```
$access_token_escaped = substr($access_token, 0, 15) . '\!' . substr($access_token, 17);
```

...results in something of the form `'substringA\\!substringB'`.

The PHP `addslashes()` function only works on specific characters.

I'm fairly new to PHP - am I missing a trick?

Comment: Exclamation mark doesn't have any special meaning, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that says that the backslash is needed?

Comment: What you've written should work. It shouldn't double the backslash.

Comment: Please see the 'Access Protected Data' section at the bottom of this Salesforce OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow page that shows the need to escape the exclamation mark https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: Your code works as desired: https://ideone.com/vNyFtT

Comment: Are you sure the substrs are correct? You're removing two characters from the middle of `$access_token`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed, it's strange as this seems to work OK when playing on the w3schools.com 'Try it Yourself' pages. Maybe my development server is escaping the strings when echoing them to the page - I'll investigate further.